# CKEditor stylesSet preset for Bootstrap

Tags: ckeditor

Is there any ready made stylesSet setting for using the bootstrap css classes in CKEditor? I know I can build my own rules, but as there are quite a lot of default bootstrap classes it would be a great help to have a preset. I'm talking about CKEditor v4 with it's [stylesSet setting](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.stylesSet)

Answer (score 1):

You should investigate the add-ons and plugins by [searching the CKEditor website](http://ckeditor.com/search/sites/results?query=bootstrap).

The "Bootstrap Include CSS & JS" might do what you're after, though it's a commercial solution and includes more functionality than you've mentioned.

Here you can find more information about this plugin:

- [on the CKEditor website](http://ckeditor.com/addon/bootstrap-include-css-js)
- [on the js.plus website](http://js.plus/products/bootstrap-table-tools/bootstrap-include-css-js-plugin)

Note: I have no affiliation with the seller of this plugin, and I've not personally used it before. It just seems to me like the most solid pre-made solution for the functionality you've requested.

Comment: Although this might be a good addition to the rendering for the user this still does not add the bootstrap elements as classes to be selected by the user. Maybe I just have to write my own plugin for this.